# Macbook Screen Graphics Glitching From One Frame To Another

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

My MacBook Pro (13.3 inch, MacOS Sierra 10.12.15,Late 2017) started to have grey horizontal lines appearing on my screen in Mid 2018. At first I thought it was not very serious and could deal with it, but later into 2019, a dark grey translucent stripe started appearing at the bottom of the screen.

Still, I decided not to take action. It was when at the bottom of my screen started glitching and it started to take the graphics of a different app (swiping left/right with three fingers), but only at the bottom of my screen. The bottom started to have coloured glitches and little do you know, the top of my screen started to do the same. It was at the start of summer when it started to become worser than ever.

Because the usage of my MacBook has increased far more hours than usual, the whole display started to fail. For example, if I was to be watching Netflix, the screen would freeze on one frame, but continuing what was supposed to have been playing underneath the first frame that was frozen. I could only see what was happening because it froze translucently, where I would immediately turn off my laptop to prevent further damage.

Other example that may occur would be when I am on one tab (let's say, a Spotify playlist), and then swipe across my trackpad to a Google Document filled with writing, and then to my desktop. My screen would have my desktop wallpaper with a translucent overlay of both the playlist and the text that I would have been working on, on the document. I figured the fault may have been because of a crack at the bottom my screen, although I do not understand how that may have happened.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take it to an authorized apple repair facility.  They are the only ones that can get new parts.  The labor is reasonable, $75 an hour if I remember right.  You can try and go with a used screen but you're taking your chances.  If you have apple care then they might replace the screen for free.  I can tell you that the retina screen is about $450 on a MacBook.  They will also do a free diagnostic to make sure the quote is accurate.  Looking on Amazon the price is about the same so might as well let the pros do it.

As far as the diagnostic part try plugging in an external display.  If the display glitches there too then it's probably not the screen.  Let us know what happens on an external display.